# Suppose that $A$ is an $m\times m$ skew-symmetric matrix. Show that $-A^2$ is a nonnegative definite matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Please help me
I know that all elements of $-A^2$ is positive-semidefinite,
but I don't know the next.

Comment: Hint: for skew-symmetric $-A^2=A^TA$.

Comment: What is "psd"?${}{}{}$

Comment: @MPW Sorry, it was my edit. I thought that the title was enough.

Comment: Thank you for everyone :) I just registered this site today and don't know how to insert mathematical symbols.. you are all awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = -A^T \implies -x^TA^2x = -x^T(-A^T)Ax = (Ax)^T(Ax) = \left\|Ax\right\|^2$$

Comment: +1, but I'd write it as follows: $ x^T(-A^2)x = x^T(-AA)x = x^T(A^TA)x = (Ax)^T(Ax) = \left\|Ax\right\|^2 \ge 0$